# Is there an option to change the language of Borderlands 3 on Steam?

Tags: steam, borderlands-3

The game is, for whatever reason, German on my system. Now, I'd like it in English. I'm aware that there is a function in the Steam properties that allows me to set the language. However, the game apparently ignores that. I tried setting it to German and back, then French. Nothing helped.

[image]

I also couldn't find any option in the game itself to change the language.

So, is there any other way to change the language of Borderlands 3?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay, barely 2 minutes later I figured something out. Apparently, you have to add `-language="en"` as startup param in the properties, then the game will boot on english.

[image]

Comment: This works, but this is stupid on the dev's part...